# Set css properties with a json

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

i've follow the [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) description for setting up the css properties of an element with javascript, but i cant figure how to do it with a json object.

my code is this :

```
var style = {
    position:'fixed',
    top:0,
    right:0,
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
    background:'red'
}


var el = document.getElementById( 'some_id' );
for( var key in style ){
    el.style.key = style[key]
}
```

but when a run my script i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: do you actually have an element on the page that has `some_id` as that error looks as though `el` is null i.e. there is nothing on the page called `some_id`.

Comment: You mean JavaScript object. That is not JSON. Also, W3Schools is not W3C.

Comment: In my index.html i have an div element with id="some_id"

Comment: Are you running this script after the document loads?  If not then this is why you are seeing this error.  Also all the for loop is doing is setting a property in style called 'key' to the next style property.  So after the for loop you will end up with `el.style.key == 'red'` what I think you are trying to do is `el.style[key] = style[key]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Code example:

```
Object.assign(document.querySelector('.my-element').style, {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    background: 'red'
})
```

Example on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/b6hexafL/4/

Answer (score -1):

You should write:

```js
for (var key in style) { 
    el.style[key] = style[key]
}
```

Comment: sorry guys, i not seems to work. i mean..  all i'm trying to do is to set the css properties with a for loop , iterating through an object.

Comment: i think that the problem is about set up the "key" variable in el.style.key = css[key] inside the loop. 
because when i iterate key stand for the name of the property and css[key] stands for the value of the property ( i change style  for css )

Comment: I do it ,please check the example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZHfs/1/)
and tell me your think

Answer (score -1):

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/l1ght/LE2eu/1/) of what you are trying to implement:

```js
for(var key in s) {
    el.style[key] = s[key]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work well if you want to generate one or more iframes on loading:

```
    var dir,name,ele,style,k,v;
    dir = ...
    name = ...
    ele = $(document.createElement("iframe"));
    $("#layout",parent.document).append(ele);
    ele.attr({
        src: dir +"/" +name +".html",
        id: dir +name
    });
    style = nset[dir].monitor[name].css;
    $.each(style,function(k,v){
        ele.css(k,v)
    });
    ele.load(function(){
        //next iframe or start function ... can use loaded frames
    });
```

with relevant part of nset like this:

```
 "lert": {
        "css":{
            "left": 100 ,
            "top": 0 ,
            "width": 320 ,
            "height": 480 ,
            "display": "none",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "backgroundColor":"white"
        }
   }
```